# Intersection of half planes vs union?

Tags: convex-analysis

> [image]
>
> [image]

Can someone explain to be why we are taking intersection instead of union? Because taking the union means we are also taking the union of ALL the $y$s in $S$ no?

Answer (score 0):

Intersection is "in all the sets simultaneously". Now, check again the definition of the set.

Comment: And union isn't "all sets"?

Comment: Element $\in$ union iff $\in$ *some* of the sets. In *all* the sets simultaneously (smaller thing) is the intersection.

Comment: But I can union everything no?

Comment: You can, but the union isn't your set.

Comment: Um, why…?Union here is also taking everything

Comment: Easy example in the plane: what points are in all the lines $y=ax$ **simultaneously**?